# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Error when run method in separate thread in c# 2.0

Tags: c#

i got a code to invoke any method through thread.

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Export());
```

here i  tried to run Export() method through thread and got compilation error. what is wrong in the code. i am using c# 2.0 version. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does method `Export` return a delegate of type `WaitCallback`? If not then you're supplying the wrong parameter to `QueueUserWorkItem`. To be clear, you need to supply a delegate that conforms to the following signature:

```
public delegate void WaitCallback(
    Object state
)
```

So, method `Export` should have the following signature:

```
public void Export(object state)
```

and be supplied to `QueueUserWorkItem` as follows:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Export)
```

or, if `Export` has a different signature then you could use an intermediate delegate to call it:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state=>Export())
```

or if `Export` needs parameters, you could:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state=>Export(some,parameters))
```

Answer (score 2):

`QueueUserWorkItem` takes a delegate, but you're calling the `Export` method and then trying to pass the *result* of `Export` to the `QueueUserWorkItem` method. In other words, it's as if you're running:

```
var result = Export();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(result);
```

That's clearly *not* going to be running `Export` in another thread...

Assuming the signature of the `Export` method is correct, you just need to change it from a method invocation to a method group conversion:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Export);
```

EDIT: If you need to give arguments to the Export method, the simplest way of doing this is to use a lambda expression (assuming you're using C# 3). For example:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => Export(filename));
```

Comment: how to pass method argument if require because u told me not give parenthesis i mean (). plzz show me the solution with sample code.

Comment: @Thomas: See my edit. But it's really important that you actually *understand* what's going on here - you may want to read up on delegates in general and lambda expressions in particular.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to write `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Export))` and modifying export to have a single parameter of type object, ie:

```
Export(object state)
{
......

}
```

the state is a parameter you can pass-trought to the callback function when you call `QueueUserWorkItem()`

Answer (score 1):

Providing `Export` matches the delegate that is to be supplied into `QueueUserWorkItem` do:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Export);
```

By writing `Export()` with parentheses you are *calling* the method instead of passing to `QueueUserWorkItem` to be called on a separate thread.

Comment: how to pass method argument if require because u told me not give parenthesis i mean (). plzz show me the solution with sample code.